# HttpContext.Current.Session destroyed between pages

Tags: asp.net-4.0

I'm having a bit of a problem where in the HttpContext.Current.Session object appears to be being destroyed between page requests and posts. I'm a bit confused as in my development environment this isn't a problem yet in a stg environment it happens.

Now I have checked all of the common problems and so far nothing seems to resolve the problem. Both dev and stg environments are the same (same iis, same versions of .net, same os and configs, all patches upto date). The web.config also matches up in both environments and the sessionState is set as follows:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="15"/>
```

On top of this all pages that require the session context all inherit from

```
IRequiresSessionContext
```

To be sure I've also checked the IIS setup and have confimred that SessionState is enabled on the application as well.

At a loss, and no more hair to pull out.

Comment: Try changing your session state mode to StateServer, and see if that changes anything. I have seen some weird stuff before when using InProc session mode (e.g. Session variables not available for a duration for no apparent reason).

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue before, check the Windows Event Log to ensure that the Worker Process is not being forced to recycle.

There may be something in your code that causes the Worker Process to force itself to recycle or crash in which case when the session is stored inProc it will loose all session values it's holding.